# Swing graphics Update image position after performing zoom

Tags: java, swing

I have the following variables that represent the position of the image (image is drag-able):

```
private int translateX, translateY;
```

And I render the image like with the `paintComponent` method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    g2d.drawImage(image, (int) (translateX * zoom), (int) (translateY * zoom), (int) (image.getWidth() * zoom), (int) (image.getHeight() * zoom), null);
}
```

Where `zoom` is the zoom amount (min `0.8`) and I multiply image dimension by the zoom.

This is how I handle the zoom value in my controller:

```
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    int delta = e.getWheelRotation();
    double temp = map.getZoom() - (delta * 0.1);
    temp = Math.max(temp, 0.8);
    temp = Math.max(temp, 0.8);
    if (temp != map.getZoom()) {
        map.setZoom(temp);
        map.repaint();
    }
}
```

What happens here, is that the zoom works great, zooms into the center like it should, but what I have is a big map image inside a JPanel that has size limits (`getWidth()` and `getHeight()`) and when you drag the map image, you can't go out of the panel bounds unless the map image is there, but if it's the end of the map image width or height, it will stop at the maximum, I do these bound calculation like this:

```
public void translateSafely(int x, int y) {
        if (!(translateY + y > 0 || (translateY + y) * zoom < getHeight() - image.getHeight() * zoom)) {
            this.translateY += y;
        }
        if (!(translateX + x > 0 || (translateX + x) * zoom < getWidth() - image.getWidth() * zoom)) {
              this.translateX += x;
        }
        this.repaint();
}
```

`getWidth()` and `getHeight()` are the methods from the inhering `JPanel`

This will make you able to drag the map (by adding x and y from drag event) with limits, if the map is ending on the map by calculating the map width or height with panel width and height.

## The problem

If you zoom in, and drag your map to the left and then zoom out, the map will go outside the bounds (negative x) and stay there and you will not be able to move it back because of the limits unless you zoom back in and move it to the right.

The question is, how do I make the map move back without jumps when I zoom out?.

GIF sample of the problem:

https://gyazo.com/ba1d69f2720dee10a19ba65bdac0e81a

Comment: @copeg No because I do need the negative x/y values to make the user able to see the whole image while dragging. Because if you're in a zoom, you won't see the whole image in the bounds of the JPanel, so you drag to see places. But when I zoom out I need to make it autoamtically go back so it wont be out of bounds and make it unmoveable and stuck at negative.

Comment: its unclear what you want - your zoom algorithm doesnt work correctly - try more

Comment: @gpasch What do u mean? please elaborate. The zoom works fine, but not with the dragging

Comment: `when I zoom out...autoamtically go back so it wont be out of bounds...` When you zoom out, re-position the [x,y] coordinates such that the center of image is identical to that of before. You can probably determine this algebraically, something like  `C = scale*(W-p)/2` (where `C` is center and `p` is position) and solve for the next p from the previous `scale` and `p`. An [mcve] would help

Comment: Sorry I edited the question with updated code and added example gif

Comment: I don't see a [mcve], just snippets. Please read the link.